# Save settings button and back to previous activity

Tags: java, android

I have an activity that has edit text and you can type your name in it, and when you click Save button you will be redirected to `MainActivity`, but I don't want to open `MainActivity` by `Intent`, I make that save button save your name with shared prefs and everything works fine but I don't want to open my Main in `Intent` I want that when I clicked on save button the current activity that saves data close and previous activity open.
sorry for my bad English.
this is my code for save button

```
        submitButt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v.getId() == submitButt.getId()) {
                String name = inputName.getText().toString().trim();
                if (isValidInput(name)) {
                    Intent setint = new Intent(SettingsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    setint.putExtra("name", name);
                    saveData();
                    startActivity(setint);
                    Toast.makeText(SettingsActivity.this, "Settings Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Use finish() for back to MainActivity

Comment: Only use an Activity for a different flow of user experience. To collect your user's name, create a PopupWindow that covers the entire screen, containing the EditText. Then this can pass the result back to the current activity as simple variables, without the overhead of re-invoking an entire Activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you just open the PreviousActivity instead of the MainActivity. Add a checker inside the PreviousActivity if "name" has data or not. You can also use `finish();` this will kill the activity.

** Update **

In your MainActivity, let's say you have TextView name. Add:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();

    // Check your variable if it has value or none
    textViewName.setText(variableForSharedPref)

}
```

Then you can proceed with usual process to go in Settings and Go Back to MainActivity.

Comment: I try that and it's work but when i click back button on my phone previous MainActivity with old data will show up. do i need to kill previous MainActivity in onStopped? if i remove intent i have a problem with setint.putExtra("name", name);

Comment: In the intent before you leave MainActivity add finish(); it should solve your problem.

Comment: i try that too but i have another activities and if i open them when i click back the app will close, i can make button for each activities to open Main but if someone click back button on its phone, app will be closed cause no MainActivity will be available.

Comment: Ah I get what you mean, you should override onResume of MainActivity and do the update of textview or what from there. Don't add finish();

Comment: Can i ask you to show me what to do with code? I'm new on android programming.

Comment: Thanks, that works, i have less than 15 rep i just wanted to tell you Thanks a lot

Comment: It's fine no worries, you can mark my answer as answered :)